API stops working on Express server side randomly
This is my server code:
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = express()
const port = 3000;
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    await axios.get("<functional URL confirmed>")
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


The above code sometimes works perfectly and logs the data as expected. Most other times however, it outputs a very long error involving 10 or more ENETUNREACH and ETIMEDOUT errors.
What I have already tried to solve this:

Checked my internet connection and speed. Everything is a-ok.
Checked my API quota. I am not violating it. I know because I can npm run dev my frontend which uses that api with the same url and output the same data with no errors even while I see this error on the backend
Checked the URL. I know it's correct because of the same reason as above.
Tried waiting for a minute before re-running the same code. It worked. Then I ran it again. Didn't work.
Assumed it was a time limit thing. Wrong. Waited for 15 minutes before re-running, still didn't work.
Cut and pasted the same URL again just to change something. Data logged successfully.
Re-ran the code. Error again.

I don't know what's causing this erratic behaviour.
In case anyone wonders why I'm even using an Express server when the API can be called directly in my React frontend, it's because this preliminary call isn't causing issues but some other stuff on the same URL is giving me CORS errors. However the url I'm using here to test my server-side code is the same one that is definitely functional in the frontend.
Can someone please explain what is going on behind the scenes?
EDIT:
What ended up working was disabling IPv6 on my system. I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on why that worked, and maybe how I can fix the code so that the user doesn't have to mess around with their grub settings to use my app? Thanks!

This is a local issue, your Axios requests are timing out, as the error log says.

axios.get("<functional URL confirmed>") - yet the error confirms the URL does not always function within the timeout limit.

@robertklep I see. How do I fix the timeout error?

If the endpoint does return but later - you can increase the timeout. If it doesn't, then either fix the system on the other end (if you control it) or implement some sort of caching (on your end, if you don't control the other one). If you expect some magic to keep the code yet also make it work - there isn't one. You need to identify the problem and address it.

@VLAZ , thanks for your help! I understand that there's no magic. I don't control the third party API, no. I added a timeout of 10000 milliseconds. It didn't fix the fact that the code sometimes runs but most of the time doesn't. The server also doesn't seem to wait the set amount of time before logging the same errors.

Please see if this works for your : https://www.grouparoo.com/blog/node-js-and-ipv6

Also please note that this is NodeJS issue basically, please see here : https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3528
